# Adding AuthenticationStatement block to SAML token using Java Metro STS

Tags: saml, java-metro-framework

I'm developing a java Security Token Service using the Metro framework in NetBeans 8.0 following this tutorial: https://metro.java.net/2.0.1/guide/Building_custom_STS_.html

I've implemented the STSAttributeProvider interface to provide custom attributes and build up the `<AttributeStatement>`. In the same manner I would like to add an `<AuthenticationStatement>` block in the SAML response but I can't seem to find out how to do this. What would be the correct approach?

Thanks!